# Symfony4 Form not submitted

Tags: forms, symfony4

I have a problem with my Form in symfony4, when I click on the submit button it is not submitted (It doesn't pass the `isSubmitted` condition)

Here is my Form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Backend\Team;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Class AddTeamForm
 * @package App\Form\Backend\Team
 */
class TeamForm extends AbstractType
{

    const NAME = 'name';
    const WEBSITE = 'website';
    const IRC = 'irc';
    const DISCORD = 'discord';
    const TWITTER = 'twitter';
    const FACEBOOK = 'facebook';
    const HIDDEN = 'hidden';

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
            ->add(self::NAME, TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.name'
            ])
            ->add(self::WEBSITE, TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.website'
            ])
            ->add(self::IRC, TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.irc'
            ])
            ->add(self::DISCORD, TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.discord'
            ])
            ->add(self::TWITTER, TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.twitter'
            ])
            ->add(self::FACEBOOK, TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.facebook'
            ])
            ->add(self::HIDDEN, CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.team.form.hidden'
            ]);
    }
}
```

and Here is my action

```
    /**
     * @Route("/add", name="add")
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(TeamForm::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            var_dump('submitted');
            if($form->isValid())
            {

            } else {
                var_dump('non vlide');exit;
            }

            $team = $form->getData();
        }

        return $this->render('backend/team/add.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

and my view

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {class: 'ui form inverted', novalidate:'novalidate', 'action': url('admin_team_add')} }) }}

{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div class="ui grid two column">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve wide column">

            {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            {{ form_row(form.website) }}
            {{ form_row(form.irc) }}
            {{ form_row(form.discord) }}
            {{ form_row(form.twitter) }}
            {{ form_row(form.facebook) }}

            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                    {{ form_widget(form.hidden) }}
                    {{ form_label(form.hidden) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.hidden) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="ui button green" value="{{ 'admin.team.form.btn-create' }}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Like I said, When I click my submit button, the var_dump 'submitted' is not shown. The page refreshes but nothing happen, like a normal page refresh.

I must miss something but can't figure what ...

Comment: Do you have an entity "Team"? If yes, instance it and send it as the second parameter of createForm trait.

Comment: It force me to add a '?' in the return type of all my getters, like this : `public function getName(): ?string`
Dunno if it's really good, but that works, and now my `$form->getData()` return a Team instance, so that's good.

Comment: that's a PHP 7.1 thing, nothing to do with Symfony 4. Read about Return type declarations on PHP 7. Let me know if my comment  helped you to solve your problem, if so, I will add it as answer of this question.

Comment: Oh after instanciate it and pass to createForm It worked. but for the others that could read that, I inform that symfony call getters, and on an empty instance it raise this error and it force to use the '?return_type'

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your route name exist:

```html
php bin/console debug:router admin_team_add
```

if it's not exist , change your view action to :

```html
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {class: 'ui form inverted', novalidate:'novalidate', 'action': url('add')} }) }}
```

or change your controller route name to :

```html
/**
     * @Route("/add", name="admin_team_add")
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
```

Comment: Got an answer in the comment of my post, but thank you. It was juste an error with PHP7.1+ syntax, I forgot to add a `?` in my return type hint and that caused errors